# How to create a Multi-Dimensional Array from a String Literal

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, string-literals

I'm new here and I'm new to `C` too.
I have the following pointer `ptr` which points to a `String Literal`:

```
const char *ptr = "Hello my dear World";
```

What I need to do is to create a Multi-Dimensional Array which should contain those words which should result in something similar to this:

```
char arr[MAX_WORD][MAX_SIZE_OF_WORD] = {"Hello", "my", "dear", "World"};
```

What I have so far is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD 4
#define MAX_SIZE_OF_WORD 6

int main(void){
    const char *ptr = "Hello my dear World";
    char arr[MAX_WORD][MAX_SIZE_OF_WORD] = {0};

    while ( *ptr != '\0'){
        /* code here */
        ptr++;
    }

    size_t len = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;
    for (size_t x = 0 ; x < len ; x++){
        printf("%s",arr[x]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

My logic was to iterate `ptr` until i reach `'\0'` and to copy those words  inside `char arr[][]`, but the problem is, I don't know how to do that.

How to copy the content of `ptr` inside `arr[][]`?

Comment: Please if you find something Wrong with the Question let me know and not just down vote it.

Comment: You can use the function `strtok` from string.h, but in this case you'd have to copy the string to a unidimensional array first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD 4
#define MAX_SIZE_OF_WORD 6

void split_to_array( char ( *a )[ MAX_SIZE_OF_WORD ], size_t n, const char *s )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; *s != '\0' && i < n; i++ )
    {
        while ( isblank( ( unsigned int )*s ) ) ++s;

        if ( *s )
        {
            const char *last = s;
            while ( ++last && !isblank( ( unsigned char )*last ) );

            size_t length = ( size_t )(last - s + 1 < MAX_SIZE_OF_WORD ? 
                            last - s + 1 :
                            MAX_SIZE_OF_WORD );

            strncpy( a[i], s, length );
            a[i][length -1] = '\0';

            s = last;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *ptr = "Hello my dear World";
    char arr[MAX_WORD][MAX_SIZE_OF_WORD] = {0};

    split_to_array( arr, MAX_WORD, ptr );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < MAX_WORD; i++ ) puts( arr[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
my
dear
World
```

Comment: I removed my comment just in the same  time you answered to it. Yes there was a mistake made by me, but now that I have no changes i get this: `error: conversion to ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ from ‘long int’ may change the sign of the result` Here ==>  `size_t length = last - s + 1 < MAX_SIZE_OF_WORD ? last - s + 1 : MAX_SIZE_OF_WORD;`

Comment: @Kevin A good point. You should use casting to size_t. I will change the code in a moment.